# JMeter Cant make GET HTTP request work, works fine in PostMan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to do a GET HTTPS Request via JMeter. It is a simple request with content-type=application/json, and an auth token. Now for unknown reasons it works perfectly without any issues/problems in Postman, but in JMeter I'm getting an error.

I'm new to JMeter so I can only assume I am just setting something incorrectly.

The HTTP Request I am sending is:

```
 https://www.server.com/api/userinfo?fields=['id']
```

In postman I get a 200 response with the expected JSON response.
In JMeter however, it gives me the error:

```
Could not parse fields query. Must be valid JSON.
```

I've tried messing with the 'send parameters with the request' option in JMeter by removing the ?fields=['id'] from the Path, and instead setting them in the parameters area, but that gives me the exact same 400 error response code.

Also, if I use the send parameters section, and I look at the request, it doesn't seem to be using the parameters i've set. So I went back to passing the parameter directly in the URL path.

Comment: The error implies that the request is not a proper JSON(as you have specified `content-type:application/json`). Can you share what exactly does the API expect as request parameter?

Comment: It is expecting a parameter 'fields' and its value is a list of properties that i want returned. Specifically I want the users 'id' returned, so I am passing the parameter ?fields=['id'].

If I send the parameter via the Path, it gives the error mentioned above about it must be a valid JSON. If I try to send the parameter via the 'Send Parameters With the Request' section, as far as I can tell it is not being sent at all, and gives me an error that the fields parameter is missing.

Comment: Show how you submit in postman

Comment: More confusion: In Postman if I use double quotes for ["id"] it works. If I use single, I get the same 'must be valid json' error. However in JMeter, if I use double quotes, it gives me an error that im using illegal characters.

Comment: @user7294900 in Postman, I send that exact same request as in my original post, except i use double quotes. In JMeter, double quotes give me an error for an illegal character.

Comment: Where/what is the JSON body?

Comment: I'm not sending a JSON body. The only data being sent is via the parameter ?fields=.

In Postman and using curl, there is no actual JSON body being sent. I think what is going wrong is 2 different issues that I don't know how to solve.

1) JMeter doesn't like the use of the double quotes in ?fields=["id"]. It gives an error that the double quotes are an illegal character. If I use single quotes, I get the invalid JSON error. In Postman, if I use single quotes, I also get the invalid JSON error. So I need to somehow figure out how to use double quotes.

Comment: 2) The "Send Parameters with Request" area does not seem to work at all. I can maybe bypass the issue in #1, by sending the parameters in the parameters area. Unfortunately when I use this area, it does not send the parameter. I don't know how to make this area work at all...

Comment: Here is the working curl:

curl -XGET server.com/userinfo194c1fff-dbf9-4cc3-a784-c89b7bfd3c48?fields=\[%22id%22\] -H 'Authorization: Bearer 3568512b1a3cd488eebe0979a7489d86ede2cbe3' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -ik -g

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:: The issue is that JMeter does not like the usage of double quotes in the Path field. You can get by this by using %22 in place of double quotes. This solved the problem of not receiving an error when passing the parameter through Path.

Comment: For what its worth, I still have no idea why JMeter won't send anything I enter in the parameters section of the HTTP request.. That would be really awesome to figure out, if anyone has any information on that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your Test Plan
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. You might also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as a child of your request and configure it to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

The sent data can be verified using View Results Tree listener:

[image]

---

Also be aware that you can easily create a JMeter test from Postman by just recording the request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Comment: If I use the 'Send Parameters With the Request' UI section to enter parameters, they are not passed to the HTTP Request. This was verified by checking the HTTP tab in the Request.

If I pass the parameters via the Path, they are passed to the HTTP Request. This was also verified by looking at the HTTP tab in the request.

As far as I can tell, that section of JMeter does not work at all, and all parameters need to be passed through from the Path.